# Extracting the word from a string. Non regular pattern

Tags: r

I wanna try to seperate the numbers from the words. Can anyone help me. Try to use the `word()` and the other functions but doesnt work. Saw someone use regular expression to extract non regular pattern. How?

```
                      order_status_id.status
1              1\tMenunggu Pengesahan Peniaga
2                         2\tPesanan diterima
3                          3\tPesanan ditolak
4                       4\tPesanan dibatalkan
5                5\tPesanan sedang disediakan
6     6\tPesanan sudah siap dan boleh diambil
7  7\tPesanan sudah siap dan dalam perjalanan
8              8\tSahkan kod kepada pelanggan
9                  9\tMenunggu pengesahan kod
10                       10\tMenunggu bayaran
11                      11\tTransaksi selesai
```

I tried the  `word()` function and `str_extract` and `gsub(".*?([c(a-z,A-Z]+).*", "\\1",x)` but it only seperate the first word.

Comment: can you put this in a reproducible way? I'm confused if you are just trying to extract out numbers or extract out words too

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(order_status_id.status = gsub("[0-9\\\t]", "",order_status_id.status))
```

output:

```
 order_status_id.status                 
   <chr>                                  
 1 Menunggu Pengesahan Peniaga            
 2 Pesanan diterima                       
 3 Pesanan ditolak                        
 4 Pesanan dibatalkan                     
 5 Pesanan sedang disediakan              
 6 Pesanan sudah siap dan boleh diambil   
 7 Pesanan sudah siap dan dalam perjalanan
 8 Sahkan kod kepada pelanggan            
 9 Menunggu pengesahan kod                
10 Menunggu bayaran                       
11 Transaksi selesai
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(order_status_id.status = c("1\tMenunggu Pengesahan Peniaga", 
"2\tPesanan diterima", "3\tPesanan ditolak", "4\tPesanan dibatalkan", 
"5\tPesanan sedang disediakan", "6\tPesanan sudah siap dan boleh diambil", 
"7\tPesanan sudah siap dan dalam perjalanan", "8\tSahkan kod kepada pelanggan", 
"9\tMenunggu pengesahan kod", "10\tMenunggu bayaran", "11\tTransaksi selesai"
)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```